# Create users under an alias

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create an user under an alias. for eg. Say I've a company and my AWS account is `My-Org-007` and under this I can create users. But I want to do this using API. when I went through the documentation, it is given as below.

```
https://iam.amazonaws.com/?Action=CreateUser
&Path=/division_abc/subdivision_xyz/
&UserName=Bob
&Version=2010-05-08
&AUTHPARAMS
```

Here I'm confused about the `Path`(where can I get the path) and `AUTHPARAMS`(I have `Access key ID` and `Secret access key`, are these that I need and how d I access it in API Call).

please let me know on how I can do it using the API.

Thanks

Comment: The "path" is optional (default is /) and used to create a nested structure e.g. you can create an IAM user Bob with path /department/engineering/
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-friendly-names

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very compelling reason to use AWS APIs directly, you would want to use the AWS SDKs. SDKs make your life a lot easy in achieving what you want. Check CreateUser documentation here for NodeJS SDK(SDKs for other programming languages like Go, Java, Python, .Net, C++ ... are also available for you to use): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IAM.html

/* The following create-user command creates an IAM user named Bob in the current account. */

```
var params = {
  UserName: "Bob"
 };
 iam.createUser(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
    User: {
     Arn: "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Bob", 
     CreateDate: <Date Representation>, 
     Path: "/", 
     UserId: "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE", 
     UserName: "Bob"
    }
   }
   */
 });
```

Calling the createUser operation

```
var params = {
  UserName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Path: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
iam.createUser(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```